# function to check what next id is after some have been deleted in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of contacts that I can navigate through in the detailed view like this:

```html
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['/details',  friend.id - 1 ]" *ngIf="!(friend.id == 1)">
        Prev
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/details',  friend.id + 1 ]" *ngIf="!(friend.id == totalContacts)">
        Next
    </a>
</nav>
```

This creates a problem, however, when I have deleted some of the IDs.
For instance, if id '4' is deleted, when I try to go from 3 to 5, it finds nothing.

How can I surmount this without dramatically changing how I am navigating?
like maybe changing this to use index instead of ID?

Sample of array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "John Doe", 
        "address": "123 Main St",
        "phone": "123-456-7890"
    },
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Jane Smith", 
        "address": "456 Side St",
        "phone": "123-456-7891"
    },
    {
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "James Smith", 
        "address": "456 Side St",
        "phone": "123-456-7892"
    },
    {
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Mary Jones", 
        "address": "789 High St",
        "phone": "123-456-7893"
    },
];
```

Comment: have all your friends in an arrayList and navigate to the next or previos entry in the list?

Comment: Agreed, use a list and play with the index rather than the data ID.

Comment: well, they are in an array list. but how does one navigate in such a way?

Comment: can you share your friends list array?

Comment: I made an edit with the array

Comment: store the "index", so you can, e.g. `<a [routerLink]="['/details',  myArray(index-1).id]" *ngIf="index>0)">Prev</a>`

Comment: i know this is a noob question, but what do you mean specifically by 'store the index'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating an ID by adding 1 or removing 1, use the array indexes.

Supposing you are displaying `obj`, that means you already know its index in the array. If for some reason you don't, then retrieve it with `const index = arr.indexOf(obj)`.

Then your `routerLink`s will be `"['/details',  arr[index - 1].id ]"` and `"['/details',  arr[index + 1].id ]"`

Comment: figure out how to correctly call. thanks for the example.